# How do I change the menubar transparency in Lion?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

So I love the login screen in OS X lion, and I want to make my desktop look like that. I found the background image they use, but now I want to make my menu bar completely transparent like it is in the login screen.

I've tried the "translucent menu bar" option in system preferences, but thats not the same at all. I googled quite a bit about this, but I can't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Watch for updates to fix Lion issues - the developer has completed partial Lion support - http://crystalclear.musingsfrommars.org/

Comment: I don't know the answer, but [MenuBarFilter](http://eece.github.com/MenuBarFilter/) can make the menu bar *black* so I would assume it could be modified to make it completely translucent.

Comment: [UPDATE: Apparently there is no way to make it translucent, only to color it.]

Answer (score 8):

You would most likely need to use a translucent/transparent background image to accomplish what you're asking. If you know how to make an image 90% transparent then you should be able to experiment and to come up with something similar. Tweaking the UI is art in many ways, however, it's not necessarily a function of the interface creating the effect; the elements that compose it (background color, wallpaper, dock and icons) play a key role.

[posted for reference]

System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Translucent menu bar

[image]

- One app that I've used to achieve a similar effect is called Nocturne. I'm unsure of it's compatibility with Lion though.

Answer (score 1):

is this what are you looking for?

[**Menu Eclipse 2**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/menu-eclipse-2/id420041409?mt=12&ls=1)  (Mac App Store link)

[image]